# Where is the source that one is supposed take out their peyos when they are davening Shemona Esrei?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, shemoneh-esrei, payot-sideburns

There have been many times where I have seen people pull out their Peyos from behind their ears right before Shemona Esrei. Anyone I have asked said there is a source, but I can not locate it. (Supposedly there is a Yesod Vshoresh HaAvodah that mentions it).

Comment: Hi, maybe edit and clarify the question, did you intend "pull out their Peyos" to mean 1) unravel peot that were rubber banded in front of the ears, or 2) untuck peot that were stuffed behind the ears, or etc.

Answer (score 4):

יסוד ושורש העבודה בשער ה, שער הקרבן פרק ב וז"ל בא"ד : יזהר האדם בתפלת שמונה עשרה שלא יכסו שערותיו של הפאות את אזנו וכו'  וציין למקור לזה בזהר חדש כז:, ובתיקונים קכב: וקכד: עיין שם.

Comment: שלא יכסו could mean literally on the ear or it could mean in front of the ear. In which case if it was already behind the ear there would be no need to take it out, and if it was in front of the ear to maybe move it forward.

Comment: Correct. Such is stated in שו"ת אז נדברו חלק יב סימן לז.

Answer (score 2):

Having been through all of the Zohar several times I can tell you that the zohar hakadosh says that when hair is covering the ears of the person praying- it will block the 'ears of heaven' from hearing the prayer. I also remember that the yesod veshoresh hoavoda quotes this zohar somewhere. (unfortunate I cannot recall the location of either the Zohar or the YVH but I am very certain that I have seen them. I assume that this is the source of the custom that you mention.

Comment: Usually the peyos are behind the ears of the person and they take it out from behind. The Zohar you are quotings sounds like you should do the opposite!

Comment: @ Lanied Sofey, https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14707&st=&pgnum=68 says exactly your point.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Avraham and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!