# Is there any times during prayer that one can use payos?

Tags: tefilla, payot-sideburns

Is there any times during prayer where the use of payos, like kissing the tefillin in shema, is suggested?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the source that one is supposed take out their peyos when they are davening Shemona Esrei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/133001/where-is-the-source-that-one-is-supposed-take-out-their-peyos-when-they-are-dave)

Comment: There is a drinking water dispenser for your use as a courtesy.

Comment: @avrah not necessarily. I was meaning if there I a time in prayer where a certain verse is a good time to do something with the payos. Like in shema we kiss the tefillin, I was wanting to know if there is an “action” with the payos one can do when reading a specific prayer. Thanks